# Roles Hierarchy in Spring Webflux Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have implemented Webflux security by implementing:

- ReactiveUserDetailsService
- ReactiveAuthenticationManager
- ServerSecurityContextRepository

Now, I am trying to introduce RoleHierarchy following the docs here: [Role Hierarchy Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authz-hierarchical-roles)

I have a user with role USER but he is getting 403 Denied on hitting a controller annotated with GUEST role. Role hierarchy is: **"ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST"**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final DaoAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager;

    private final SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

    private static final String ROLE_HIERARCHIES = "ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST";

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(DaoAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager,
        SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository) {
        this.reactiveAuthenticationManager = reactiveAuthenticationManager;
        this.securityContextRepository = securityContextRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager)
            .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().disable()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "roleHierarchy")
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(ROLE_HIERARCHIES);
        return roleHierarchy;
    }

    @Bean(name = "roleVoter")
    public RoleVoter roleVoter() {
        return new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy());
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class DaoAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {

    private final DaoUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final Scheduler scheduler;

    @Autowired
    public DaoAuthenticationManager(DaoUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
        Scheduler scheduler) {
        Assert.notNull(userDetailsService, "userDetailsService cannot be null");
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        final String username = authentication.getName();
        return this.userDetailsService.findByUsername(username)
            .publishOn(this.scheduler)
            .switchIfEmpty(
                Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid Username"))))
            .map(u -> new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(u, u.getPassword(),
                u.getAuthorities()));
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class SecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

    private final DaoAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityContextRepository(DaoAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange swe, SecurityContext sc) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange swe) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = swe.getRequest();
        if (request.getHeaders().containsKey("userName") &&
            !Objects.requireNonNull(request.getHeaders().get("userName")).isEmpty()) {
            String userName = Objects.requireNonNull(swe
                .getRequest()
                .getHeaders()
                .get("userName")).get(0);

            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName,
                Security.PASSWORD);
            return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map(SecurityContextImpl::new);
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }


}
```

Anyway to get the role hierarchy thing working in Webflux security.

**EDIT**

Controller:

```
@GetMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
public Mono<Device> getDevice(@RequestParam String uuid) {
    return deviceService.getDevice(uuid);
}
```

Normal role authorization is working for me, whats not working is the hierarchy part.

Comment: can you add controller code too please? How did you annotate it? I'm currently facing the same problem and found a very naive solution. Check this post, it can correspond to way you annotate your controller : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5046

Comment: By the way you don't need to define and set an AuthenticationManager, you just need to define your own Bean of `ReactiveUserDetailsService`

Comment: @LG_ updated my post to add the Controller. I have added an implementation for `ReactiveUserDetailsService`, somehow my flow also needed the `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`

Answer (score 0):

Here a very naive solution by overriding DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.

I supposed you annotated your controller with this king of expression :     `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`

**securityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final DaoAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager;

    private final SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

    private static final String ROLE_HIERARCHY = "ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST";

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(DaoAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager,
                          SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository) {
        this.reactiveAuthenticationManager = reactiveAuthenticationManager;
        this.securityContextRepository = securityContextRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().disable()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(ROLE_HIERARCHY);
        return roleHierarchy;
    }

    // Overriding spring default bean 
    @Bean
    public DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        handler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return handler;
    }

}
```

Then you have to authorize spring bean overriding by modifying your application property file:

**application.properties**

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Sources : [issue 1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5046) [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4841) [role hierarchy doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authz-hierarchical-roles)

---

Going a little bit further... This part can be optimized and cleaner.

Using url patterns setup from ServerHttpSecurity object.

Note that the following setup won't use role hierarchy :

```
  @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager)
            .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ROLE_USER") // This won't use role hierarchy because it will use implemention of hasRole defined in your 'reactiveAuthenticationManager'
            .anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().disable()
            .build();
    }
```

A solution could be to create your own implementation of `ReactiveAuthorizationManager` and overriding `check` method in order to call  `access(...)` from your http object (`ServerHttpSecurity`). Ie :

```
public class CustomReactiveAuthorizationManager<T> implements ReactiveAuthorizationManager<T> {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomReactiveAuthorizationManager.class);

    private final RoleHierarchyVoter roleHierarchyVoter;

    private final String authority;

    CustomReactiveAuthorizationManager(String role, RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        this.authority = ROLE_PREFIX + role;
        this.roleHierarchyVoter = new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<AuthorizationDecision> check(Mono<Authentication> authentication, T object) {

        return authentication
                .map(a -> {
                    ConfigAttribute ca = (ConfigAttribute) () -> authority;
                    int voteResult = roleHierarchyVoter.vote(a, object, Collections.singletonList(ca));
                    boolean isAuthorized = voteResult == AccessDecisionVoter.ACCESS_GRANTED;
                    return new AuthorizationDecision(isAuthorized);
                })
                .defaultIfEmpty(new AuthorizationDecision(false))
                .doOnError(error -> logger.error("An error occured voting decision", error));
    }

}
```

and then calling access method :

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager)
            .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/user/**").access(new CustomReactiveAuthorizationManager<>("USER", roleHierarchy))
            .anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().disable()
            .build();
    }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but somehow managed to have a workaround by having my own custom annotations. Adding it as one of the answers.
Do give +1 if it works for you as well

Comment: @Karshit That's very weird that worked for me but not for your configuration. What is not working exactly? Did you try to override `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` ? Could you share a repo so I can try to make it work? Thanks

Comment: Sure, I'll put the code in a repo and share with you

Answer (score 0):

One way I was able to achieve role hierarchy in Webflux was by creating custom annotations.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public @interface IsAdmin {

}
```

---

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'USER')")
public @interface IsUser {

}
```

---

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'USER', 'GUEST')")
public @interface IsGuest {

}
```

–––––––––––––––––

And annotating the controllers like this:

```
@GetMapping
@IsUser
public Mono<Device> getDevice(@RequestParam String uuid) {
    return deviceService.getDevice(uuid);
}

@PostMapping
@IsAdmin
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Mono<Device> createDevice(@Valid @RequestBody Device device) {
    return deviceService.createDevice(device);
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's a cool workaround but you are still not using role hierarchy.